# Constrain image Movement in Specific Area in Window RT App

Tags: image-processing, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-phone-8.1

Ok.
To describe what I want to do, have you ever used Telerik Crop function Image Editor control?
I want exactly same functionality.

I want to use that control but, I am working on Universal app that has no control like Image Editor from telerik.

That control does are
1. There is a fixed rect or canvas for cropping image.
2. If the original image is in the area of canvas(or Rect) image's opacity = 1(i guess) and if the original image is out of canvas area, image looks dim(maybe opacity 0.5 or some)
3. Constrain original image movement in the canvas.

I will implement this function in Image.ManipulationDelta event.
Do I have to get each point value of canvas? or can I do it by using Width or Height of Canvas?
How Do I do that?

Can anyone help me?
any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that particular control, but I think I understand what you want.

To constrain the movement of an Image within a Canvas you can check where the Image will end up in your ManipulationDelta and limit any translation, scaling, and rotation appropriately. If the bounding box of the Image after the transform applies is within the Canvas then apply the transform. Otherwise roll it back and do nothing. I have sample code for this in my blog entry: [Constraining manipulations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/06/10/constraining-manipulations.aspx)

To dim the area outside of the crop I'd create a shape and fill it with a partially transparent brush. The all-in-one code framework sample [How to crop bitmap in a Windows Store app](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSWin8AppCropBitmap-52fa1ad7) demonstrates this technique. I believe the sample targets Windows Store 8.0 apps, but essentially the same code should work on Windows Store 8.1 or Windows Phone Store 8.1 apps.

Comment: Thanks for the sharing code. but can you explain more about TransformToVisual and TransformBounds method does in your code?

Comment: UIElement.TransformToVisual provides a GeneralTransform that will convert one UIElement's coordinates to another's. TransformBounds is the method on GeneralTransform to actually convert a Rect (generally one UIElement's bounding box) to the other's coordinate system. See the remarks on the MSDN docs for TransformToVisual at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.transformtovisual.aspx